# Relative include paths when building an RPM for a python extension using distutils

Tags: python, rpm, distutils, python-extensions

Using python 2.6, I'm attempting to build an RPM for a python C extension module.

The `setup.py` that I'm using contains something like:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

foo_ext = Extension('foo',
                    sources=['foo.c', '../src/common.c'],
                    include_dirs=['../includes'])

setup(... , ext_modules=[foo_ext])
```

If I run `python setup.py build` from `/devel/foo` for example, it compiles and builds without any errors, and `gcc` is called with the correct paths, i.e.:

```
gcc ... -I/devel/includes ...
```

When I use `python setup.py bdist_rpm` instead, then the relative paths used above are converted to absolute paths relative to the RPM build dir, this results in `gcc` trying to compile using:

```
gcc ... -I/devel/foo/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD/includes ...
```

Compilation then fails as a required `.h` file is not found in the include path.

Any suggestions or workarounds to this?

Comment: As for now, *distutils* from Python 2.7 still suffers that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by setting an environment variable during the first pass through the script, which is then read again when building the RPM:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

src_path = os.path.abspath('../src/common.c')
inc_path = os.path.abspath('../includes')

if 'SRC_PATH' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['SRC_PATH'] = src_path
    os.environ['INC_PATH'] = inc_path
else:
    src_path = os.environ['SRC_PATH']
    inc_path = os.environ['INC_PATH']

foo_ext = Extension('foo',
                sources=['foo.c', src_path],
                include_dirs=[inc_path])

setup(... , ext_modules=[foo_ext])
```

Comment: Looks like a huge kludge. There should be a way to make that buggy `setup.py build_rpm` copy the entire source tree into its build directory.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve a similar problem by providing *distutils* with a proper `MANIFEST.in` file, which enumerated all header files I wanted to include. In my case it was like this:

```
include src/_rvlm_fdtd/include/rvlm/fdtd/* –or–
recursive-include src/_rvlm_fdtd *.h
```

but I think this will not work with your `../` paths. Instead I recommend you putting all your source code inside a package base directory.

The reason why RPM build phase was not able to find out your headers is because it builds a source distribution first (with `setup.py sdist`) and unpacks resulted tarball into a temporary build directory. So your source distribution just did not contain all files necessary for building.